# Save list from a custom meta box?

Tags: posts, metabox, list, jquery-ui

I have a simple list (`ul>li`) which is manipulated with jQuery UI in a custom meta box.

How would I go about saving the contents of the list during post save?

I already have the save function ready, but how do I get the HTML data into PHP so I can put it in the database with `update_post_meta`?

The list looks like (with class names etc):

```
<ul>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

'Text 1, Text 2, Text 3' would be saved.

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the code. But, what about making a mirror inside a hidden input field, which will handle the data to be saved?

Comment: That's kind of the process I'm trying at the moment, hidden input that keeps track of the items as a comma separated list, didn't know if there was a 'proper' way to do it.

Comment: AFAIK, only form data will be submitted...

Comment: A hidden textarea box did the trick, used javascript to update it every time the list was rearranged.

Comment: Please mark the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a hidden input field. Make jQuery reflect the contents of the visible list into the hidden field.

Update the meta data using this field and build the initial list based on its values.